# SWFUpload using https does not work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, https

I am using [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org) to upload files to a database (Windows XP) over https. Everything works as expected in IE (7 and 8), but using my Firefox 3.3.15 it fails without error message. Using the upload mechanism using http works fine.

I found this [thread](http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/347) using google. They describe that installing the CAs certificate as trusted issuer would help. Unfortunatly it did not (it was a certificate issued by a CaCert authority).

It works on the machine of my colleague who uses Firefox 3.3.15, but he cannot recall that he did anything special to make it work. I had a look at other machines using Firefox and none of them were able to upload a file to the database.

I red that SWFUpload uses flash and that flash might use other certificates than Firefox itself. Does anyone know anything about it?

**What can i do to make it work?
Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of the session. If your system had to do a validation of login, when you upload your file, your session will be lost if you use Firefox or Chrome. Internet Explorer doesn't have this problem.

You can refer to [this discussion](http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/1551).

Someone who always had this problem suggested to pass the session value or read it from the cookie and then pass it to the server.

Comment: http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/cookiebugdemo/index.php

Comment: that url is the demo in the swfupload offical upload

Comment: cookie seems to work, i get "FlashCookie set to Sep 21, 2011 12:21:14.000000" usinf Win XP, Firefox 6

Comment: what is the language you use? jsp or asp or php ? asp and php had its solution, only struts2 did not soluted

Comment: i am using perl on the server side

Comment: sorry,i am never used perl. keep studying and good luck to you.